# facebook meta tags don't work with facebook sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I added fb meta tags in the heads section

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Title of the site</title>
<meta name="description" content="blah normal">
<meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Open Graph META Tags"/>
```

And I added a share button from Facebook via an iFrame from the facebook developers site with the previously added appId and changed the original developers.facebook.com from the sharing button to my site.

It works but there are no meta tags being crawled. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which url are you trying to share? And what does the debugger say? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: it says "Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped."

Comment: I also saw through the feature of FB what FB is seeing and there is no fb meta tag (and not the real index file I was redirecting to), probably because the domain I bought is just iframing as a redirector instead of a DNS to webhost redirect (I entered a domain like www.blahblah.com/blah/index.html and chose an URL frame in the domain settings).

AND it says now "Object at URL 'http://www.xxxxx' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided."

Comment: You need to add the tags on the page that Facebook requests. So if it is www.blahblah.com/blah/index.html the tags needs to be on that page

Comment: They ARE on that page! But when I click on facebooks "What facebook sees when crwaling this site" is just a site which basically says "this browser does not support iframes, click HERE ot get to www.blahblah.com/blah/index.html" where I originally typed www.thisurl.com (which iframes blahblah.com/blah/index.html)
I dont want to enter the original URL..

Comment: Then they are not on the page. The url that you give Facebook needs to contain the tags